# jquery disable by form all but one checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have form I am disableing all the fields by form tags unless a certain criteria is met.  I want to disable the entire form (working) but then I want to enable a set of check boxes by class (not working) should this work? see below

```
if (sharesNegative=1) {
    moAlert('Negative Share:','If Account Number Reassignment is not due to fraud,\
bring all shares positive before changing account number.' );
    $('form[name=accountChange]').prop('disabled',true);
    $('.fraudYesNo').prop('disabled',false); //not working 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`:input`**](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector.

```
$("form[name=accountChange] :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: as I stated above the disable part works fine, it's he enbleing of the checkboxes by class that is not working,

Comment: @user3657756 can you add your HTML?

Comment: <tr class='main'>
    <td class='indent' ><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox fraudYesNo' name='yesFraud'>Yes 
    
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox fraudYesNo' name='noFraud'>No</td>
  </tr>

Comment: here are the check boxes.  the rest is about 400 lines and contains member information so I can not cut and past it

Comment: took me a second to see what you were saying above, if the entire form is disabled I have enable the entire form but if I disable input boxes I can enable them one at a time.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a form, only form elements.

```
$('#disabler').on('click', function(){
  $(':input').prop('disabled',true);
  $('.fraudYesNo').prop('disabled',false); 
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y8ffe8gw/, HTML Spec here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

Also, while not part of your question, note that `if (sharesNegative=1) {` will always be `true` because with a single `=` you're assigning the value of the variable. You want to use `==` to compare so `if (sharesNegative==1) {...}`